# Java 8 lambda scoping issue

Tags: java, closures, java-8

```
    int x = 1;
    Consumer<Object> f = (i) -> {
        int x = 1; // invalid
    };
```

vs.

```
    Consumer<Object> f = (i) -> {
        int x = 1;
    };
    int x = 1; // valid
```

Imagine those two blocks inside a method. Why is the second block valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first block you are "[shadowing](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15)" the original `x` variable. You will not be able to access the first `x` anymore by creating a new `x`.

The second block is okay, because the second `x` is created on a moment when the first `x` does not longer exists (it is *out of scope*).

Basically: in the first case, you are trying to have two variables called `x` at the same time. In the second case, you are creating two `x` variables after each other: their lifetimes will not overlap.

Comment: why isnt the "scope" symmetric then. IF lambdas are so transparent then it should be symmetric

Comment: But scope simply isn't symmetric. Not even for constructs like `for` loops or `if` statements.

Comment: lol, so lambdas (as if-blocks etc.) dont create a naming scope, but create a lifetime scope? why?

Comment: I don't know lambdas too well, to be honest. I'm just saying scope not being symmetric isn't a surprise. I'll leave talking about lambdas up to those who know them better.

Comment: but you can answer why do if-statements do so: why dont they introduce naming scope but do introduce a lifetime scope?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want inner scopes to inherit the outer scope, but you don't want the outer scope to inherit the inner scope. And that means that you can't redeclare a variable in an inner scope because it conflicts with the declaration in the outer scope. But you *can* declare a variable in the outer scope *after* an inner scope because there are no possibilities of conflicts (the inner scope is already "gone" at that point). It is, of course, somewhat of a language design choice. But a common one and one that makes sense to me.

Comment: It would, of course, be a perfectly legal design to allow redeclaring (as in "shadowing") variables in inner scopes. Again, it's just language design. But it introduces a level of confusion (dealing with variables of the same name with different values depending on the scope) that has no actual benefit (just using a different name is easy enough).

Comment: +1.  This has nothing to do with lambdas; e.g. anonymous classes would impose the same constraints.

Answer (score 5):

This is very similar to normal Java scopes:

```
int i;
{
    int i;      // invalid
}
```

vs.

```
{
    int i;      // valid
}

int i;
```

Comment: I was going to write the exact same thing!